# Proving $\mathrm{Hom}(f\circ f', g'\circ g) = \mathrm{Hom}(f', g')\circ \mathrm{Hom}(f,g)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, group-homomorphism

$
\newcommand{\Hom}{\mathrm{Hom}}
$

> If $i:A\to A$ and $j:B\to B$ are the identity homomorphisms of the
> modules $A$ and $B$ over $R$, then:
>
> $$\Hom(i,j):\Hom(A,B)\to\ Hom(A,B)$$
>
> is the identity homomorphism of the module $\Hom(A,B)$. If $f:A'\to A$,
> $f':A''\to A'$, $g:B\to B', g':B'\to B''$ are homomorphisms of modules
> over $R$ we have
>
> $$\Hom(f\circ f', g'\circ g) = \Hom(f', g')\circ \Hom(f,g)$$

Just as a clarification, my book defines $\Hom(f,g)$ as being the following thing:

> Let $f:A'\to A$ and $g:B\to B'$ denote arbitrarily given homomorphisms
> of modules over $R$, and consider the modules $\Hom(A,B)$ and $\Hom(A',
>  B')$. Define a function
>
> $$h:\Hom(A,B)\to \Hom(A', B')$$
>
> by taking $h(\phi) = g\circ \phi\circ f$
>
> for every $\phi\in \Hom(A,B)$. Clearly $h$ is a homomorphisms of the
> module $\Hom(A,B)$ into the module $\Hom(A', B')$ which will be denoted
> by the symbol
>
> $$\Hom(f,g)$$

In order to prove $\Hom(f\circ f', g'\circ g) = \Hom(f', g')\circ \Hom(f,g)$, I must see $f\circ f'$ as one function, and $g'circ g$ as another, and apply the definition given in the book. So my $h$ will be a function such that $h(\phi) = (g'\circ g)\circ \phi \circ (f\circ f')$. I tried to use associativity, for example, to see $g'\circ (g\circ \phi \circ f)\circ f'$. I think I can kinda see $\Hom(f,g)$ in the middle, and $\Hom(f',g')$ in the points, but I'm lost. Could somebody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$
\newcommand{\Hom}{\mathrm{Hom}}
$
You almost have the solution there. Let us give the functions names to make things a bit easier on ourselves.
\begin{equation} h_1 = \Hom(f \circ f',g' \circ g), \, h_2= \Hom(f',g'), \, \text{ and }\, h_3 = \Hom(f,g) \end{equation}
Then by definition,
\begin{equation}h_1(\phi)=g' \circ g \circ \phi \circ f\circ f' \end{equation}
Likewise we have,
\begin{equation}h_2 \circ h_3(\phi)=h_2(g \circ\phi \circ f)= g' \circ g \circ \phi \circ f \circ f' 
\end{equation}
So we have
\begin{equation}\Hom(f \circ f',g' \circ g) = h_1 = h_2 \circ h_3 = \Hom(f',g') \circ \Hom(f,g)
\end{equation}
as desired.